# Consecutive Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, asynchronous

I need a little help in my application design. Using Ajax I want to get some PHP resources consecutively but I don't think if it is good to retrieve them using JQuery `$.ajax` method.

I think something like this means wrong design:

```
$.ajax({
     url: SERVERURL+'index.php/home/checkAvailability',
     datatype: 'text',
     success: function(data){
        if(data == 'unavailable'){
           // do stuff
        }
        else{
           $.ajax({
              url: SERVERURL+'index.php/home/getWebTree/',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data){
                 // do stuff
              }
           });
        }
     }
  });
```

Can anybody give me a suggestion to get a better design? How can I do the same in a better way?

Thanks!

EDIT: like @arnorhs tell us, using async parameter could be a solution. But I'm still think that there are other solutions instead of using consecutive ajax calls.

EDIT2: `checkAvailability` and `getWebTree` are PHP functions using CodeIgniter that I've developed to get resources from an external server using `Http_Request` object.

```
function checkAvailability() {
      $this->load->library('pearloader');
      $http_request = $this->pearloader->load('HTTP', 'Request');
      $http_request->setURL('http://myurl');
      $http_request->_timeout = 5;
      $http_request->sendRequest();
      $res = 'available';
      if (!$http_request->getResponseCode())
         $res = 'unavailable';
      return $res;
   }
```

Comment: We're just [Stackers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/what-should-the-users-of-stack-overflow-be-called/6261#6261), actually :) Also, is there a reason why you call a web service to check for availability, instead of having the server reply with `503` or similar to your `getWebTree` call and handling that case in an AJAX `error` handler?

Comment: It would also be interesting to know why you want to do multiple calls at the same time and not just do a single one an provide more information in the request

Comment: The resources are loaded from external servers. getWebTree is just a function that I've created to retrieve one of them. So I can't handle using 503 code, or I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Fran, if I understand correctly, you're issuing an AJAX call to a web service which, in turn, proceeds to call another web service using PEAR's `HTTP_Request` and then relays the result. Is something preventing you from calling the second web service directly from the client and ditching the PHP layer?

Comment: The whole site is building using Javascript, so I can't call them directly from it because these are in other servers different from mine.

Comment: @Fran, you might want to consider [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Doing the calls all the same time

If you want to do all the ajax calls at the same time, you can simply call an ajax request right after the others. You could even assign them the same success handler. If you want a more "elegant" approach, I would do something like this:

```
// define a set of requests to perform - you could also provide each one
// with their own event handlers..
var requests = [
    { url: 'http://someurl', data: yourParams   },
    { url: 'http://someurl', data: yourParams   },
    { url: 'http://someurl', data: yourParams   },
    { url: 'http://someurl', data: yourParams   }
];

var successHandler = function (data) {
    // do something
}

// these will basically all execute at the same time:
for (var i = 0, l = requests.length; i < l; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: requests[i].url,
        data: requests[i].data,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: successHandler
    });
}
```

.

### Do a single request

I don't know your use case, but of course what you really should be trying to do is retrieve all the data you're retrieving in a single request. That won't put a strain on your server, the site/application will seem faster to the user and is a better long term approach.

I would try to combine `checkAvailability` and `getWebTree` into a single request. Instead of receiving the data in Javascript as text objects, a better approach would be to receive them as json data. Luckily PHP provides very easy functions to convert objects and arrays to json, so you'll be able to work with those objects pretty easily.

**edit**: small modifications in the PHP code now that I understand your use case better.

So something like this in the PHP/CI code:

```
function getRequestData () {
    if (checkAvailability() == 'available') {
        $retval = array (
            'available' => '1',
            'getWebTree' => getWebTree()
        );
    } else {
        $retval = array (
            'available' => '0'
        );
    }   
    header('Content-type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');     
    echo json_encode($retval););
}
```

And the Javascript code can then access those by a single ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://yoururl/getRequestData',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (jsonData) {
        // we can now access the parameters like this:
        if (jsonData.checkAvailability) {
            // etc
        }
        //and of course do something with the web tree:
        json.getWebTree
    }
});
```

.

### Execute the requests synchronously

If you set the `async` parameter in the $.ajax options to `false` the functions will be made in a synchronous fashion so your code halts until execution has been completed..  or as the documentation says:

> **asyncBoolean**
>
> Default: true
>
> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @armorhs Thanks :) I know that parameter, but do you know a better way to do the same?

Comment: I know no other way if you want to do it consecutively (not all at the same moment), but I've edited my answer to provide an alternative approach.

Comment: I added an example how you can combine it into a single request

Comment: @Fran Verona: I read the answer of **arnorhs** before writing my answer. Like **arnorhs** I wanted to suggest you to combine the requests to the single request. You don't commented the part of answer. Why you see any problem to follows the way in your environment? One more question: why you use in the `ajax` url the `SERVERURL` prefix? Do you try to call **another server**? It is important to understand whether you need use `jsonp` or at least `'&jsonCallback=?'` as the part of your url.

Comment: You really want to avoid `async: false` unless you know _exactly_ what your doing. It blocks the browser aswell.

Comment: @arnorhs thanks for such a wonderful answer. Since "successHandler" is  handling the output coming from the page where we sending AJAX request, what should we do if we want to print that message. I tried to alert both data and "successHandler", but it both print nothing. Please help

Answer (score 10):

If you really need to make two calls you can be more expressive with [Deffered](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) that was introduced in jQuery 1.5.

```
$.when(checkAvailability())
   .then(getWebTree())
   .fail(function(message){
       if(message === 'Not available!')
       {
           // do stuff
       }
   });

function checkAvailability(){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
    url: SERVERURL+'index.php/home/checkAvailability',
    datatype: 'text',
    success: function(data){              
        if(data == 'unavailable'){
            dfd.reject("Not available!");
        }
        else{
           dfd.resolve();
        }
    }
    });

    return dfd.promise();
};

function getWebTree(){
    $.ajax({
        url: SERVERURL+'index.php/home/getWebTree/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            // Do stuff
        }
    });
};
```

Check it out live at http://jsfiddle.net/jimmysv/VDVfJ/

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you could make use of  the deferred object that's new to jquery 1.5

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 0):

Programming with commands that should be handled in queue live from callbacks, and this is just what you are doing.

You are defining a callback on the success of your request and send another request, once it is triggered and validated.

Nothing wrong with that.

The only thing, to keep it better maintainable, is defining the callbacks as functions before the call and just giving $.ajax the function names

```
function myFunc() {
    //Do stuff
}

$.ajax{ {
    success: myFunc
} );
```